# in google sheets, how do i use SUMIFS to sum one of two columns depending on the content of a third column?

Tags: google-sheets

Im trying to calculate a sum. In one column (COL H), I have my criteria, (50%, 90% or 100% are the options). In another column,Col K, I have the values for calculating the sum. Finally, I have a third column (COL I) that wants to overwrite the second column if necessary and take the place of the second column in the sum calculation.

It goes like this, In H2, i choose an option from the dropdown, in this case "100% only ->". In I2, I want to sum all values in COL K where COL H says 100%. This I can accomplish with the following formula:

=IF(H2="100% only ->",SUMIF(H4:H100,"100%",K4:K100)

The last piece of the puzzle is to allow COL I to override COL K if applicable. In this picture, you can see that I would want 500 to override 18513 in the sum calculation, so the total would be 500+41,290.42 (42420.42). I just cant figure out how to get this to happen! Thanks so much for any help!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=IF(H2="100% only ->",SUMIF(INDEX(IF(LEN(I4:I100),I4:I100,H4:H100)),"100%",K4:K100))
```

OR

```
=IF(H2="100% only ->",SUMIF(byrow({I4:I100,H4:H100},lambda(z,torow(z,1))),"100%",K4:K100))
```